# Change site url when moving site to another url?

Tags: migration, deployment

Is it really neccessary to put `WP_HOME`, `WP_SITEURL` in `wp-config.php` or set these settings via admin panel every time when moving a WordPress instance to another url (for example: moving from dev environment to production)? Is there any better strategy?

Answer (score 4):

Those parameters and admin settings change the URLs in the database. The only other way to do that is run SQL queries on the DB in phpmyadmin to change them:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

**Update 1/16/2015: it's much better to use a script that deals with serialized data, such as** [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

**Update 9/15/2023** Even better to use WP CLI: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Comment: You should be careful with this approach because some plugins store serialized arrays in wp_options (like ContactForm7) and a brute replace (unless both domains have the exact same number of characters) may brake the plugin configuration.

Comment: These queries correctly find/replace in serialized data and don't break the plugin or the data.

Comment: Not if you have a serialized array in a meta_value in wp_postmeta, and that array contains the site url (if old and new urls have different str_len, of course)

Comment: @MZAweb: You're right, my mistake; update added.

Answer (score 2):

What I do here is I keep an entry in my /etc/hosts file pointing the site domain to 127.0.0.1. Most of the time the line is commented so my machine points to the production site, and when I'm developing something I just uncomment the line and the domain will point to my dev box.

I know it's kinda ugly, but since Wordpress puts the domain in a lot of fields in the database (especially if you need to work with real data in your development environment), it's the fastest method I could come up with.

Answer (score 2):

When you move from one server to another the problem could be URLs that WP serialized in DB.
To do a safe search and replace you can use this tool [search replace db](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

Is very simple, follow the instructions and remember to remove the script when done.

Answer (score 0):

You could put those settings in an external file and exclude it from your publishing process.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mess with core files, I just move the themes and plugins around instead. I develop locally and zip the themes and plugins for production. I have about ten WordPress installs most internal and this has worked well for me so far.

I also, don't move much data around so this answer may not help you. There are some pretty extensive free plugins for backing up data and restoring.

Answer (score 0):

Use on the top of your functions.php: 
update_option('siteurl','http://yoursite.com');
update_option('home','http://yoursite.com');

Navgigate through your site a bit, login the backend en remove these lines.

This should be sufficient.